# How to create 2x2 grid of tables in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am trying to create a 2x2 grid of tables in HTML, where each table is independently collapsible. I can't seem to figure out a proper solution. For example, the version below somewhat works, but unfortunately when the R1C1 table is hidden, the row 2 tables become joined with the first row.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Attempt at a 2x2 grid of tables, each independently collapsible
Based on following web pages (among others):
- http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/javascript/f1030.shtml
- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp
-->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>2x2 table grid</title>

    <style>
      table, th, td
      {
      border-collapse:collapse;
      border:1px solid black;
      width=50%
      }
    </style>


    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function setDivStyle(table, style) {
        // Set the display style
            var tbl = document.getElementById(table);
            tbl.style.display = style;
        console.log(table + " display style set to " + style)
          }
    </script> 

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="r1">
      <h2>Row 1</h2>

      <div id="r1-controls">
    <a id="r1c1-hide" href="javascript:setDivStyle('r1c1', 'none')">Hide R1C1</a> 
    &nbsp;
    <a id="r1c2-show" href="javascript:setDivStyle('r1c1', 'inline')">Expand R1C1</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a id="r1c2-hide" href="javascript:setDivStyle('r1c2', 'none')">Hide R1C2</a> 
    &nbsp;
    <a id="r1c2-show" href="javascript:setDivStyle('r1c2', 'inline')">Expand R1C2</a>
    <br>
      </div>

      <table id="r1c1" style="display: inline; float: left">
    <tr>
      <th>R1C1a</th>
      <th>R1C1b</th>
      <th>R1C1c</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
      </table>

      <table id="r1c2" style="display: block; float: none">
    <tr>
      <th>R1C2a</th>
      <th>R1C2b</th>
      <th>R1C1c</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div id="r2">
      <h2>Row 2</h2>

      <div id="r2-controls">
    <a id="r2c1-hide" href="javascript:setDivStyle('r2c1', 'none')">Hide R2C1</a> 
    &nbsp;
    <a id="r2c1-show" href="javascript:setDivStyle('r2c1', 'inline')">Expand R2C1</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a id="r2c2-hide" href="javascript:setDivStyle('r2c2', 'none')">Hide R2C2</a> 
    &nbsp;
    <a id="r2c2-show" href="javascript:setDivStyle('r2c2', 'inline')">Expand R2C2</a>
    <br>
      </div>

      <table id="r2c1" style="display: inline; float: left">
    <tr>
      <th>R2C1a</th>
      <th>R2C1b</th>
      <th>R2C1c</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
      </table>

      <table id="r2c2" style="display: block; float: none">
    <tr>
      <th>R2C2a</th>
      <th>R2C2b</th>
      <th>R2C1c</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
      </table>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are some of your tables `inline`, and others `block`? Pick one (probably `block`), and stick with it. Also Don't use inline styles, or set styles with javascript, use CSS to set your styles and use javascript to switch classes.

Comment: Thanks, the inline/block usage was a combination of confusion and inconsistent editing. (I'll look into defining classes for this.)

Comment: I'm not adding this as an answer, but I've created a jsFiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/Bx8Un/. This demonstrates the use of toggling classes instead of setting styles manually and putting javascript in your HTML (generally bad practice). I have used jQuery to bind the events because I find it easier and neater than pure JS.

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems similar to this before. Its the `float:left` that is causing Row 2 to move up when R1C2 is hidden. I recommend creating another function that will toggle `float:left` when you hide R1C2 like so:

```
function setFloat(element, style) {
    var el = document.getElementById(element);
    el .style.float = style;
    console.log(element + " float style set to " + style)
}
```

and calling it: `javascript:setDivStyle('r1c2', 'none');setFloat('r1c1','none');`

Comment: You don't even need to do that, you can just apply `clear: both` to the h2 element underneath and it won't float up.